# InfoPath cannot submit the form because it contains errors

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list .

I edit the form  with infopath. When I do the new information if required field is empty ,the following error

**InfoPath cannot submit the form because it contains errors. Errors are marked with either   a red asterisk (reguired fields) or a red , dashed border (invalid values).**

Comment: Seems to be going something wrong in role you defined.
Can you please elaborate your question more so I can get more Idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard infopath error notification mechanism(if form is opened in browser). This message means that value for one of your field is empty(or some invalid values as message says). Required field indicates with red star by default. But you can customize tool tip for required field and apply some formatting if field is empty (for example red background if field value is empty).

To do this, you need to uncheck "Cannnot be blank " settings for control and then add custom rule: Home ribbon tab, Rules-> Ad Rule->Is Blank->Show Validation Message or\and Formatting(bad). Two rules will be added to our field, in rule settings you can specify what formatting to apply and validation screen tip.

Comment: thanks a lot , I defined a custom role, but again the error

Comment: When does this error appear? When your field value and you click "Save"?

Comment: when field is empty and click "Save"

Comment: Ok, this is expected InfoPath behavior, this error indicates, that you need fill all required fields

Comment: I set custtom rule : is blank->screentip : this filed cannot be blank ->show screentip only , but show this  messagebox

Comment: You cannot remove this messagebox, because this is by design infopath behavior.

Comment: I can not  change the message ?

Answer (score 0):

See this link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointinfopath/thread/5428ea5b-11fc-4543-98e8-160fa993aaf6/

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.